# What is the purpose of yearmonth() and as_tsibble() in this code?

Tags: r, time-series

In this code, DK is a dataset:

[image]

Now, what is the function of yearmonth() nad as_tsibble() here?

```
DK["date"] = yearmonth(DK$date)
DK_ts = as_tsibble(DK, index=date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions come from the R package `tsibble` which is short for time series tibble. They represent temporally structured longitudinal tables in which each row is a time point. See documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsibble/versions/0.1.0/topics/yearmonth) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsibble/versions/0.1.0/topics/as_tsibble).

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), by = "1 month")
yearmonth(x)
# <yearmonth[12]>
# [1] "2016 Jan" "2016 Feb" "2016 Mar" "2016 Apr" "2016 May" "2016 Jun" "2016 Jul" "2016 Aug" "2016 Sep" "2016 Oct" "2016 Nov" "2016 Dec"
```

`as_tsibble` will convert an ordinary data frame into a one which is aware of the time points.